# Is this a correct usage of struct?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  struct database
  {
      char name[10];
      int number;
      int roll;
  };

  struct database s1,s2;

  printf("enter name, number , roll: ");
  scanf("%c%d%d",&s1.name,&s1.number,&s1.roll);
  scanf("%c%d%d",&s2.name,&s2.number,&s2.roll);

  printf("Entered value is :");
  printf("%c%d%d",s1.name,s1.number,s1.roll);
  printf("%c%d%d",s2.name,s2.number,s2.roll);
}
```

I've been trying to get output but I don't know if this correct Or should I access them individually? Help would be very much appreciated! thanks :)

Comment: `%c` – you're trying to get a single char only. Try: `"scanf("%9s . . .", s1.name, . . .)`

Comment: Your use of `struct` is correct, but your use of `scanf()` and `printf()` is not. The format specifier `"%c"` defines a one-character input, while you're probably trying to read and print a string of characters... You may want to learn using `"%s"` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the specific struct only within the function body, then your declaration will suffice. But, note that if you want a `struct` to be used throughout the program, then it needs to be defined like this:

```c
struct database {
  ...
};

int main(void) {
  struct database s1, s2;
  ...
}
```

Also, you're trying to accept a single `char` value:

```
scanf("%c%d%d", &name, ...);
//   --^^--
```

Here, you are expected to get a char from the user:

```
scanf("%9s%d%d", name, ...);
```

**Note:** The `%9s` is specifically given to prevent input buffer overflow.

A nicely structured program would look like (notice comments):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// Don't use magical numbers for constants in the program
// The use macros for this will suffice and look a ton cleaner
#define MAX_LENGTH 64
#define FMT_LENGTH "%63s"

// Our structure
struct database {
  char name[MAX_LENGTH];
  int number;
  int roll;
};

int main(void) {
  // You are here only creating single instances of struct
  struct database s1, s2;

  printf("Enter name, number and roll: ");

  // Always check if the values are correctly assigned to their respective
  // variables, if not, print error and exit (in this context)

  if (scanf(FMT_LENGTH " %d %d", s1.name, &s1.number, &s1.roll) != 3) {
    printf("error: One of the values are incorrectly assigned.\n");
    return 1; // Exit Failure
  }

  // Same with s2

  printf("Name: %s | Number: %d | Roll: %d\n", s1.name, s1.number, s1.roll);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"It's good practice to define structs outside of functions"* - Why?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with defining a `struct` type inside a function if it's only needed within that function; it helps avoid namespace pollution.  It's just that it's rare for that to be the case; `struct`s are most often used for passing data between functions.  (So if you're defining a `struct` inside a function, you might think about whether the usage is simple enough that you don't really need a `struct`, or whether your function is so complex that it should be broken into several functions.)

Comment: @NateEldredge That's a good point. Check out the edit – I've changed my words in the beginning lines.

Comment: Edited to maintain some consistency with your message (_Don't use magical numbers_)